# Job fails on exporting data from HDFS to mysql using sqoop in Cloudera

Tags: mysql, hadoop, sqoop, cloudera

I am exporting HDFS data of departments_export file present in HDFS location /user/training/sqoop_import/departments_export  directory. Followings are the records present in the file.

```
2,Fitness
3,Footwear
4,Apparel
5,Golf
6,Outdoors
7,Fan Shop
8,Development
1000,Admin
1001,Books
```

I want to export data to mysql table named departments_export(department_id int, department_name varchar). This table already contains following data

```
mysql> select * from departments_export;
+---------------+-----------------+
| department_id | department_name |
+---------------+-----------------+
|             2 | Fitness         |
|             3 | Footwear        |
|             4 | Apparel         |
|             5 | Golf            |
|             6 | Outdoors        |
|             7 | Fan Shop        |
|             8 | Development     |
|          1000 | Admin           |
+---------------+-----------------+
```

I am running below command for sqoop export

```
sqoop export \
--connect "jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306/retail_db" \
--username retail_dba \
--password cloudera \
--table departments_export \
--export-dir /user/training/sqoop_import/departments_export \
--batch \
-m 1 \
--update-key department_id \
--update-mode allowinsert \
```

I am getting below logs in command prompt.

```
Warning: /usr/lib/sqoop/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
18/06/10 10:42:39 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6-cdh5.13.0
18/06/10 10:42:40 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
18/06/10 10:42:41 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Preparing to use a MySQL streaming resultset.
18/06/10 10:42:43 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
18/06/10 10:42:43 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `departments_export` AS t LIMIT 1
18/06/10 10:42:44 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `departments_export` AS t LIMIT 1
18/06/10 10:42:44 INFO orm.CompilationManager: HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME is /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce
Note: /tmp/sqoop-cloudera/compile/995860db956fe955c309e42de79ab4f9/departments_export.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
18/06/10 10:42:51 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Writing jar file: /tmp/sqoop-cloudera/compile/995860db956fe955c309e42de79ab4f9/departments_export.jar
18/06/10 10:42:51 INFO mapreduce.ExportJobBase: Beginning export of departments_export
18/06/10 10:42:51 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.job.tracker is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.address
18/06/10 10:42:53 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.jar is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.jar
18/06/10 10:42:57 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.reduce.tasks.speculative.execution is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.reduce.speculative
18/06/10 10:42:57 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.map.tasks.speculative.execution is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.speculative
18/06/10 10:42:57 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.map.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.maps
18/06/10 10:42:57 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
18/06/10 10:43:00 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Caught exception 
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1281)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1355)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.closeResponder(DFSOutputStream.java:967)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.endBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:705)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:894)
18/06/10 10:43:00 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Caught exception 
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1281)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1355)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.closeResponder(DFSOutputStream.java:967)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.endBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:705)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:894)
18/06/10 10:43:00 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Caught exception 
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1281)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1355)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.closeResponder(DFSOutputStream.java:967)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.endBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:705)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:894)
18/06/10 10:43:01 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Caught exception 
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1281)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1355)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.closeResponder(DFSOutputStream.java:967)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.endBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:705)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:894)
18/06/10 10:43:01 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Caught exception 
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1281)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1355)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.closeResponder(DFSOutputStream.java:967)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.endBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:705)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:894)
18/06/10 10:43:01 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Caught exception 
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1281)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1355)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.closeResponder(DFSOutputStream.java:967)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.endBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:705)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:894)
18/06/10 10:43:02 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Caught exception 
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1281)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1355)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.closeResponder(DFSOutputStream.java:967)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.endBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:705)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:894)
18/06/10 10:43:02 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Caught exception 
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1281)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1355)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.closeResponder(DFSOutputStream.java:967)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.endBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:705)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:894)
18/06/10 10:43:02 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Caught exception 
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1281)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1355)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.closeResponder(DFSOutputStream.java:967)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.endBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:705)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:894)
18/06/10 10:43:02 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Caught exception 
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1281)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1355)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.closeResponder(DFSOutputStream.java:967)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.endBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:705)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:894)
18/06/10 10:43:02 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Caught exception 
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1281)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1355)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.closeResponder(DFSOutputStream.java:967)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.endBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:705)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:894)
18/06/10 10:43:03 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Caught exception 
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1281)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1355)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.closeResponder(DFSOutputStream.java:967)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.endBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:705)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:894)
18/06/10 10:43:04 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Caught exception 
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1281)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1355)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.closeResponder(DFSOutputStream.java:967)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.endBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:705)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:894)
18/06/10 10:43:04 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
18/06/10 10:43:04 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
18/06/10 10:43:04 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Caught exception 
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1281)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1355)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.closeResponder(DFSOutputStream.java:967)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.endBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:705)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:894)
18/06/10 10:43:04 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Caught exception 
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1281)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1355)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.closeResponder(DFSOutputStream.java:967)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.endBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:705)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:894)
18/06/10 10:43:04 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
18/06/10 10:43:04 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.map.tasks.speculative.execution is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.speculative
18/06/10 10:43:05 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1527924460497_0039
18/06/10 10:43:06 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1527924460497_0039
18/06/10 10:43:06 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://quickstart.cloudera:8088/proxy/application_1527924460497_0039/
18/06/10 10:43:06 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1527924460497_0039
18/06/10 10:43:33 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1527924460497_0039 running in uber mode : false
18/06/10 10:43:33 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
18/06/10 10:43:59 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
18/06/10 10:43:59 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1527924460497_0039 failed with state FAILED due to: Task failed task_1527924460497_0039_m_000000
Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0

18/06/10 10:43:59 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 8
    Job Counters 
        Failed map tasks=1
        Launched map tasks=1
        Data-local map tasks=1
        Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=22735
        Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0
        Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=22735
        Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=22735
        Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=23280640
18/06/10 10:43:59 WARN mapreduce.Counters: Group FileSystemCounters is deprecated. Use org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.FileSystemCounter instead
18/06/10 10:43:59 INFO mapreduce.ExportJobBase: Transferred 0 bytes in 62.3015 seconds (0 bytes/sec)
18/06/10 10:43:59 WARN mapreduce.Counters: Group org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$Counter is deprecated. Use org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskCounter instead
18/06/10 10:43:59 INFO mapreduce.ExportJobBase: Exported 0 records.
18/06/10 10:43:59 ERROR tool.ExportTool: Error during export: 
Export job failed!
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ExportJobBase.runExport(ExportJobBase.java:439)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.updateTable(SqlManager.java:965)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ExportTool.exportTable(ExportTool.java:70)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ExportTool.run(ExportTool.java:99)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:147)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:183)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:234)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:243)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:252)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have primary key on departments_export table, if not create primary key for department_id.

Try this.

sqoop export \
--connect "jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306/retail_db" \
--username retail_dba \
--password cloudera \
--table departments_export \
--update-key department_id \
--update-mode allowinsert \
--export-dir /user/training/sqoop_import/departments_export/departments.txt \
--fields-terminated-by=','
-m 1 \

I have tried and it is working fine.

Comment: I have update departments_id as primary key, and also trying to run export command similar as you mentioned, but getting jobs failed.

Comment: I tested it, even updated the departments.txt file and ran the sqoop command again and it is updating the records as well as doing inserts for new records. Did you mention the complete file name in export-dir. Also even I am getting java warnings but it is doing insert and update at end.